# VideoJS Flash fallback not working at all

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm relatively new to VideoJS; I've used it successfully in all browsers EXCEPT ie < 9. I've seen a few threads started and kind of answered RE the Flash fallback for IE 8 and earlier.

My issue is that I can't get the Flash fallback working at all. I'm using the CDN version of VideoJS and assuming that I don't need to upload anything or make any other changes to my code other than what is outlined on the VideoJS demo page.

In IE 7 and 8 I get nothing. I don't get a SWF dynamically embedded; when I check my log and do some debugging via the console I can still see the  tag; I am assuming that I should be seeing a dynamically generated and embedded .swf file for the fallback.

I've seen in a couple of threads that the latest release of VideoJS is broken / Flash fallback is not working. I've also tried a few of the workarounds outlined on the various boards - nothing at all is working for me.

Is anyone else having this issue / have you managed to resolve it? the *v*("path_to_swf") fix is not working... absolute paths are not working... preload="none" is not working...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How did you solve the issue? If you post the solution here you might help somebody with the same problem.

Comment: Such a tease! What was your solution?

Comment: @theMightyT Any chance you're going to reveal HOW you solved it?

Comment: Code example would help a lot to spot the problem

Comment: same problem here....

Answer (score 1):

Without sample code, I have no idea if this will help, but IE will not initialise embedded Flash objects that have the style: `visibility: hidden;` (including any parents of that object). You can probably see the Flash object be requested by looking at the network traffic, but it won't fire any of the Video.js events until `visibility` is set to `visible`.

IE9 will use the HTML5 player, and IE7/8 will fallback to the Flash player (which is why the problem can't be observed in IE9, unless the `techOrder` has been changed to list `flash` first).